# Is possible to have workspace switching via Ctl+Alt+Arrow NON CYCLIC?

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

After installing Linux Mint 16, and installing "Workspace grid (2D) and switcher", workspace switching started to work in a cyclic way. If you have many workspaces (4x4 in my case) navigating them in cyclic way feels like solving a Rubik's Cube.

I.e. if you have 2x2 workspaces, pressing Ctrl+Alt+RightArrow moves you to workspace top-right workspace, pressing again moves you to top-left workspace, then top-right, then top-left and so on.

Before version 2.0 pressing Ctl+Alt+RightArrow had taken you to top-right workspace and never moved you again from there.

**Is there any way to return to the old behaviour?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm on Cinnamon 2.0.14 and I seem to have the behavior you describe by default. There's a setting to activate workspace cycling, perhaps you have done so?

Go into Cinnamon Settings => Workspaces and make sure that "Allow cycling through workspaces" is not selected:

[image]

Comment: Wow!! I'll try it tomorrow! (This problem keeps from using Cinnamon 2.0 on my "production" computers).

Comment: Yes, it works!!